# Filter out rows by accessing a nested element in a row

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with some Yelp data. Here is how a row from the provided .json file looks like:

```
{"business_id":"f9NumwFMBDn751xgFiRbNA",
"name":"The Range At Lake Norman",
"address":"10913 Bailey Rd",
"city":"Cornelius",
"state":"NC",
"postal_code":"28031",
"latitude":35.4627242,
"longitude":-80.8526119,
"stars":3.5,
"review_count":36,
"is_open":1,
"attributes":{"BusinessAcceptsCreditCards":"True","BikeParking":"True","GoodForKids":"False","BusinessParking":"{'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}",
"ByAppointmentOnly":"False","RestaurantsPriceRange2":"3"},
"categories":"Active Life, Gun\/Rifle Ranges, Guns & Ammo, Shopping",
"hours":{"Monday":"10:0-18:0","Tuesday":"11:0-20:0","Wednesday":"10:0-18:0","Thursday":"11:0-20:0","Friday":"11:0-20:0","Saturday":"11:0-20:0","Sunday":"13:0-18:0"}}
```

What I'd like to do is to access the "BikeParking" attribute within the "attributes" column and filer based off its value. Right now I have something like:

```
df.filter(functions.explode(df['attributes']).BikeParking == False)
```

This, however, returns the following error:

```
"pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Generators are not supported outside the SELECT clause, but got: 'Filter (explode(attributes#8)[GoodForKids] = false);"
```

How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

attributes column is of **`struct`** type and **`explode`** only works with **`array or map`** types.

Try by accessing **`struct`** fields as **`<field_name>.*`**

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark.\
read.\
option("multiline","true").\
json("yelp.json").\
filter(col("attributes.BikeParking").cast("boolean")).\
show()

#+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----+-----+
#|        address|          attributes|         business_id|          categories|     city|               hours|is_open|  latitude|  longitude|                name|postal_code|review_count|stars|state|
#+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----+-----+
#|10913 Bailey Rd|[True, True, {'ga...|f9NumwFMBDn751xgF...|Active Life, Gun/...|Cornelius|[11:0-20:0, 10:0-...|      1|35.4627242|-80.8526119|The Range At Lake...|      28031|          36|  3.5|   NC|
#+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+------------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Also, it appears that this only works for the first row in my dataset. Would you know how this could work for all rows?